# Why does rails crash when rotating logs? What is the proper way to rotate logs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logrotate

I did not want to go through the headache of setting up 4 node-servers with 3 applications each by using logrotate for UNIX.

So I decided to setup my rails applications with the following inside environment.rb:

```
  log_path = "#{Rails.root}/log/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"
  shift_age = 'weekly' # you can either 1) specify 2 params 50, 1024bytes OR 2) specify 1 param 'daily | weekly | monthly'
  config.logger = Logger.new(log_path, shift_age)
```

However, this caused the rails application to break once the files were rolled over.

I am wondering, what is the best way to rotate logs with rails applications?  Is it logrotate?  Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the rails app is crashing because config.logger is only evaluated once when the application starts and Logger is not closing and reopening the logfile. When the logfile is rotated you're doing the equivalent of yanking the rug out from underneath the app. (This is part of the reason apachectl has the graceful restart/reload method, to cleanly close all open logfiles.)

Comment: @nbrew - thanks, that is probably exactly what is happening, how would you recommend that we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because one process is trying to rotate the log file at the same time that the another process is trying to rotate it, a race condition occurs, and the server stops responding to requests, as a Fatal Exception is raise

Comment: So what is the solution